# How to restore ssh_config file in /etc/ssh

Tags: ssh

I accidentally deleted `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file.

I've tried purging and re-installing `openssh-server` and `ssh` but the file doesn't return.

How would I restore this file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is part of the package `openssh-client`. Therefore

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-client
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-client
```

---

Purging the package `ssh` makes no sense, it's only a meta-package for `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` and purging this package doesn't purge `openssh-client` and `openssh-server`.

Comment: That's a bit drastic.

Answer (score 8):

Try :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Comment: Thanks, and perhaps a `sudo systemctrl restart sshd`? Thanks very much, that done it. I selected install maintainers version so the file was updated but at least now I'm able to access from my local machine via ssh.

Answer (score 8):

The file `/etc/ssh_config` is a configuration file, which has special handling in *dpkg*, so it is preserved across package upgrades. If the file is deleted, this, too, is preserved, so merely reinstalling the package will not fix the problem.

Your choices are, to either

- completely remove the package including its configuration files, as A.B. [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/682072/10359), but this will remove all custom configuration for the package, *or*
- reinstall the package by hand using `dpkg`, giving it the `--force-confnew` option to overwrite configuration files.

The latter option has the advantage of keeping other customized configuration files, renamed with a suffix of `.dpkg-old`.

To do this, you need a copy of the package file,

```
apt-get --download-only --reinstall install openssh-client
```

will download it to `/var/cache/apt/archives`, and

```
dpkg --force-confnew -i /var/cache/apt/archives/openssh-client_...
```

will install it (replace the ... with the version downloaded).

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. Good job.

Comment: Why not just `sudo apt-get download openssh-client`?

Comment: Because I'm ancient, and that command was added later on, so I didn't know it yet.